# In-universe reason for why most aliens speak English in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

What is the in-universe reason for why so many extra terrestrials speak English in the MCU? Is there something like *Star Trek*'s universal translator involved?

Comment: The dupe asks about GotG but it's answer applies to the MCU as a whole

Comment: Recently watched Captain Marvel and she was wondering if her 'universal translator' was working properly the first time she met Fury at the phone booth.

Comment: "Is there something like *Star Trek*'s universal translator involved?" — Turns out there's something completely legally different from *Star Trek*'s universal translator that just happens to do exactly the same thing and have exactly the same name.